# Selector :nth-child without a break?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have this example html code.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="test"><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="test"><td>Test</td></tr>
        <tr class="test"><td>Test</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my css code is following:

```
table tbody tr.test:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: #ff00ff;
}
```

And the output is a wrong :(

**It seems that there is a break with the tr with no class.**
**Why!?**

Look at jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/Bubelbub/rFddk/

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: what do you mean by a "break" ... you're expecting it to have the red background too?

Comment: nth-child count the childs, not the elements matching the set. The result is expected. What do *you* expect ?

Comment: look at the jsfiddle, please.

I except that the "tr.class" selector select like mysql (SELECT tr WHERE class = class) etc.

And from that selected i need the :nth-child(odd/even).

I dont know why it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

No, on the contrary, the `tr` with no class doesn't affect `:nth-child()`: it can never be "broken" in that sense. If this element is the nth child of its parent, then it's the nth child, no matter what class it has/doesn't have or what element type it is, etc. The presence of `.test` in the selector simply means "this element must have the class to match". Since that element doesn't have the class then the rule doesn't get applied, simple as that.

Comment: +1. It's sad that [`nth-match`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo) is still unsupported by all browsers :(.

Comment: But how could i realize that... I have a table with "colgroups" and in a group could be two tr or one tr. And i would color the groups :(
jQuery?